# ERROR 1045(28005) : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )

Tags: mysql, users

I reinstalled `mysql-server` and I can't access `mysql` anymore :

```
ERROR 1045(28005) : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )
```

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989418/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-n ?

Answer (score 1):

You can start MySQL server and skip the grant tables to change the root password.

**You should only do this while fixing it**, and restart it normally after you've set the root password.

1. Stop the MySQL Server.

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. Start the mysqld configuration.

   `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`
3. Login to MySQL as root.

   `mysql -u root mysql`
4. Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password

   `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password