# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) no working solution

Tags: software-installation, mysql, wordpress

i used the solution here 
[ERROR 1045(28005) : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893887/error-104528005-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)
but when i use the command

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('000') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;

i get this

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: That is a mysql command, not a bash command. You run it at the mysql prompt. My guess is you skipped step 3, log into mysql as root.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/428243/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: i tried it and got  
ahmed@Anonymous:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for ahmed: 
-bash: export: `=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle': not a valid identifier
root@Anonymous:~# UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('000'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: You still skipped step 3 "mysql -u root mysql" . You will then get a mysql prompt `mysql>` . you enter the UPDATE command at the mysql prompt, not the bash prompt. Nowhere in the link you are following is the command "sudo -i" listed.

Comment: how can i open mysql ptompt?
when i used this 
mysql -u root mysql
i got 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Run `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` then `mysql -u root mysql` . See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/428243/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost ie dpkg-reconfigure